# how to check if a html table has duplicated rows in js and sum inputs instead of insert another row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, duplicates

I'm learning JS while doing a POS System, and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to check if the product added is already scanned before inserting and if so, change the quantity input instead.

So far when I scan the product id it inserts without a problem, but when I scan the same id it inserts in a new row. It seem that my function comprobacion isn't working. I tried with other using a for to search in the rows, and I tried some solutions that I found online but nothing seems to work.

here is an example of what its happening

https://gfycat.com/respectfultemptingeastrussiancoursinghounds

idProductos is the primary key and is hidden in the rows, so im introducing codigo (it's another unique column, both cannot be null).

Can someone help me? I'm lost.

This is my code

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "../php/venta.php",
        data: param,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != null) {

                var idProductos,
                    Codigo,
                    nombre,
                    precioVenta;

                // console.log(data);

                var rows = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                idProductos = rows[0].idProductos;
                Codigo = rows[0].Codigo;
                nombre = rows[0].nombre;
                precioVenta = rows[0].precioVenta;

                (idProductos)

                if (comprobacion(idProductos) == false) {

                    var nuevoValor = $(parseInt($('.inputCantidad')[i]).val()) + 1;

                    $($('.inputCantidad')[i]).val(nuevoValor);

                    var valorImporte = $($('.inputprecioVenta')[i]).val() * nuevoValor;

                    $($('.inputImporte')[i]).val(valorImporte);

                } else {

                    var table = document.getElementById('tablaVenta');

                    var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
                    newRow.align = "center";

                    var contentRow =
                        '<td><input type="hidden" class="inputId" value="' + idProductos + '">' + Codigo + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + nombre + '</td>' +
                        '<td><input class="inputprecioVenta" value="' + precioVenta + '"></td>' +
                        '<td><input class="inputCantidad" value="1"></td>' +
                        '<td><input class="inputImporte" value="' + precioVenta + '"></td>';

                    newRow.innerHTML = contentRow;


                    table.appendChild(newRow);

                }

            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { //errores
            alert(jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);

        },

    })

}
```

the function comprobacion

```
    function comprobacion(idProductos) {
var id = $(idProductos).val();
$('tbody tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == id) {
        return false;
    }

});
return true;
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community. For starters, please include a [mcve] to your question. Otherwise, it might take a lot more time and a heap of guessing to figure *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: `$(this)` in `comprobacion` refers to a `tr` element, which does not have a value to get with `val()`. Also returning false from the function passed to `each` just causes the `each` to stop iterating, it doesn't return false from the surrounding function.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the id to the row using a custom data attribute, like `data-id`, and use that, along with some clever selector creation to quickly identify if the id has been used before.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "../php/venta.php",
    data: param,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data != null) {

            var idProductos,
                Codigo,
                nombre,
                precioVenta;

            // console.log(data);

            var rows = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            idProductos = rows[0].idProductos;
            Codigo = rows[0].Codigo;
            nombre = rows[0].nombre;
            precioVenta = rows[0].precioVenta;

            (idProductos)

            if (comprobacion(idProductos) == false) {

                var nuevoValor = $(parseInt($('.inputCantidad')[i]).val()) + 1;

                $($('.inputCantidad')[i]).val(nuevoValor);

                var valorImporte = $($('.inputprecioVenta')[i]).val() * nuevoValor;

                $($('.inputImporte')[i]).val(valorImporte);

            } else {

                var table = document.getElementById('tablaVenta');

                var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
                newRow.align = "center";
/* Add the line below */
                newRow.setAttribute("data-id", idProductos);

                var contentRow =
                    '<td><input type="hidden" class="inputId" value="' + idProductos + '">' + Codigo + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + nombre + '</td>' +
                    '<td><input class="inputprecioVenta" value="' + precioVenta + '"></td>' +
                    '<td><input class="inputCantidad" value="1"></td>' +
                    '<td><input class="inputImporte" value="' + precioVenta + '"></td>';

                newRow.innerHTML = contentRow;


                table.appendChild(newRow);

            }

        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { //errores
        alert(jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);

    },

})
```

Then, the `comprobacion` function becomes easier:

```
function comprobacion(idProductos) {
  return $('tbody tr[data-id="' + idProductos + '"]').length === 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, i just tried the adjustments that  you gave me. Still the same problem, it still adds duplicates.

Comment: I just checked and  idProductos is unique and the primary key

https://gfycat.com/respectfultemptingeastrussiancoursinghounds

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what `comprobacion` is supposed to return; this code returns true if the id is NOT present in the table.

Comment: Yes, it returns true if the id isn't present.

Comment: And you added the line to set the "data-id" attribute? Do you fire a lot of these ajax calls in rapid succession? If the code had not appended a row to the table, and `comprobacion` got called again, I could see it failing, since the row would technically not exist in the DOM for jQuery to see it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Set id to HTML inputs, is more quick to find ProductID with JS.

```
'<td><input type="hidden" id="hid_' + idProductos + '" class="inputId" value="' + idProductos + '">' + Codigo + '</td>' +
'<td>' + nombre + '</td>' +
'<td><input id="hid_' + idProductos + '" class="inputprecioVenta" value="' + precioVenta + '"></td>' +
'<td><input id="qty_' + idProductos + '" class="inputCantidad" value="1"></td>' +
'<td><input id="cst_' + idProductos + '" class="inputImporte" value="' + precioVenta + '"></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('tbody tr td').each(function()`.
The value is in the td, not the tr

Comment: `td` elements don't have a `value` attribute either. Only `input`, `select`, `button`, and `textarea` have values

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. i didn't noticed that. Sadly still doesn't work

Comment: yes looked too quick. use $(".inputId") as the selector

Comment: you can [edit] your answer to make it correct... otherwise, it does not answer the question correctly